# Checking for Null Pointer in Ada

Tags: pointers, ada

Generally speaking, Ada will raise a `Constraint_Error` if you attempt to dereference a null pointer (access type).  However, this behavior is disabled if, for example, you have `pragma Suppress (all_checks)` in use.

Given this scenario, how would one go about checking to see if the access type points to `0x0` (null)?

Consider the following:

```
type My_Access_Type is access all My_Type'Class;

procedure myProcedure ( myAccess : in My_Access_Type ) is
begin

-- need to have check in here
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if myAccess = null then
...
end if;
```

Although it won't necessarily point to 0x0. Access types are not pointers, and may be implemented in a different way than plain addresses.

Comment: So, it was late last night, and I wasn't entirely clear as to what is going on. I am getting an issue with the debugger where when I check the value of something on the access type (using `myAccess.all`), I get `Cannot access memory at address 0x0` which makes no sense.

Comment: @theMayer, you probably need to delete this question and ask another! What does `p myAccess` show?

Comment: I agree, however, my question is no longer relevant. I have resorted to using print commands. :(

Comment: "Cannot access memory at address 0x0 " in the context of debugger usually means that the memory is not properly allocated (or has been already deallocated).

Answer (score 2):

Another option, that can help you, is to declare the pointer as "not null".

```
type My_Access is not null access My_Type;
```

this prevents the declaration of not initialized My_Access types.

```
X : My_Access; -- compile error
```

This solution as some disadvantages (see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Types/access#Null_exclusions) and its correct usage depends on your needs.

Comment: Checking disabled means this won’t work (at least, not in all cases)